# Expansion and visibility of particles because of diffusion

Tags: visible-light, mathematical-physics, diffusion, absorption

> A cloud forms as a point source containing a fixed quantity of
> particles and then expands according to the diffusion equation. Let's
> analyze how the visible size of the cloud changes with time. When is
> it the largest, and when does the cloud disappear? A part of the cloud
> is visible if the relative fraction of transmitted light satisfies the
> condition:
>
> \begin{equation} \label{eq1} I/I_0 \leq 1 - \varepsilon ,\end{equation}
>
> where $\varepsilon$ is a small value dependent on the detector (eyes,
> film, ...). Here, $I_0$ represents the incident light flux entering
> the cloud, and $I$ represents the transmitted light flux. For it, the
> following relationship holds:
>
> \begin{equation} \label{eq2} \frac{dI}{dl} = -\mu I , \end{equation}
>
> where the absorption coefficient $\mu$ is proportional to the number
> density of particles $n$.

Solution to diffusion equation is $$n(r, t) = \left( \frac{1}{4\pi Dt} \right)^{3/2} \exp{\left(-\frac{r^2}{4Dt}\right)} \; .$$

The absorption coefficient $\mu$ is proportional to the number concentration of particles $n$, as given by the equation:

\begin{equation}
\mu = \sigma n(r, t) 
\end{equation}

where $\sigma$ represents a microscopic cross-section for absorption, which will play the role of a constant in our further analysis.

To obtain the relative fraction of transmitted light, we equate the infinitesimal part of the path traveled by light $dl$ to $dz$. We can do this under the assumption that the light rays come from a distant source (the Sun), and thus are parallel and form a beam of light. As the number density is also spherically symmetric, we can choose a coordinate system with the origin at the cloud source, and the $z$ axis pointing in the direction of the light rays' propagation. This leads to:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{dI}{dz} = - \mu I ; .
\end{equation*}

**For now, let's assume that light travels through our cloud instantaneously, while the number density of particles $n$ doesn't change as light passes through it. We can fix the time $t$ and integrate over the coordinate $z$.** We get: $$\ln \left( \frac{I}{I_0} \right) = - \sigma \left( \frac{1}{4\pi Dt} \right)^{3/2} e^{-\frac{x^2 + y^2}{4Dt}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{z^2}{4Dt}} \; dz = - \sigma \left( \frac{1}{4\pi Dt} \right) e^{-\frac{x^2 + y^2}{4Dt}}$$

**My question is how do we change the integral if the assumption in bold doesn't hold?**

This means that time and position should be correleted somehow, because when light comes to the point $z$ in cloud, the time it needs to get there, the cloud will also chage its shape in that time a bit.